# Curl error Could not resolve host: saved_report.xml; No data record of requested type"

Tags: php, curl

```
<?php
```

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$url = 'saved_report.xml';


define('XML_HEADER', '*RWRESPONSE*RESPONSE*DATA*HEADER*COLUMN');
define('XML_ROW', '*RWRESPONSE*RESPONSE*DATA*ROW*COLUMN');

$headers = array();
$rows = array();

function startTag($parser, $data) { 
    global $current_tag; 
    $current_tag .= "*$data"; 
} 

function endTag($parser, $data) { 
    global $current_tag; 
    $tag_key = strrpos($current_tag, '*'); 
    $current_tag = substr($current_tag, 0, $tag_key); 
} 

function contents($parser, $data) { 
    global $current_tag, $headers, $rows;
    switch($current_tag) { 
        case XML_HEADER: 
            array_push($headers, $data);
            break; 
        case XML_ROW:
            array_push($rows, $data);
            break; 
    } 
} 




// fetch the report
$curl_object = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_object, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl_object, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl_object, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($curl_object, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl_object, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

$result = curl_exec($curl_object);
$error = curl_error($curl_object);
$info = curl_getinfo($curl_object);
curl_close($curl_object);

if ($error) {
    die("An error occured while fetching the report\n");
}


// process the report
$xml_parser = xml_parser_create(); 
xml_set_element_handler($xml_parser, "startTag", "endTag"); 
xml_set_character_data_handler($xml_parser, "contents"); 

if(!(xml_parse($xml_parser, $result))){ 
    die("Error on line " . xml_get_current_line_number($xml_parser)); 
} 
xml_parser_free($xml_parser);

for($i = 0; $i \n";
}

echo '
';

echo "$headers[3]: $rows[3]
\n";
echo "$headers[4]: $rows[4]
\n";


?>
```

while running this script , i am getting an error

"Could not resolve host: saved_report.xml; No data record of requested type"

i am not able to resolve this  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify full path of the file, e.g.:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/saved_report.xml';
```

as curl doesn't work with relative URLs