# cURL error: Could not resolve host

Tags: php, dns

A similar question has been posted at but i could not find the solution there
[Curl error Could not resolve host: saved_report.xml; No data record of requested type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298125/curl-error-could-not-resolve-host-saved-report-xml-no-data-record-of-requested)

```
<?php

$url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pakistan";
 $ch = curl_init(urlencode($url));
  echo $ch;
  // used to spoof that coming from a real browser so we don't get blocked by some sites
  $useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1";

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 4);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 8);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME, 10);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

  $content = curl_exec($ch);



  $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

if ($content === false || $info['http_code'] != 200) {
  $content = "No cURL data returned for $url [". $info['http_code']. "]";
  if (curl_error($ch))
    $content .= "\n". curl_error($ch);
  }
else {
  // 'OK' status; format $output data if necessary here:
  echo "...";
}
  echo $content;
  curl_close($ch);
?>
```

when i paste the same address in browser i am able to access the webpage. but when i run this script i get the error message. Can anyone please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `urlencode` call.

Comment: Thanks but now i am getting this error: Operation timed out after 8000 milliseconds with 432600 out of 569482 bytes received" No cURL data returned for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pakistan [200] Operation timed out after 8000 milliseconds with 432600 out of 569482 bytes received

Answer (score 3):

remove the `urlencode($url)` it should be:

```
 $ch = curl_init($url);
```

Comment: Thanks but now i am getting this error: Operation timed out after 8000 milliseconds with 432600 out of 569482 bytes received" No cURL data returned for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pakistan [200] Operation timed out after 8000 milliseconds with 432600 out of 569482 bytes received

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,60);` see http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: now 1/5 times it runs otherwise gives me apache http error: apach encountered a problem and needs to shut down sorry for the inconvenience"

Answer (score 1):

Well.

If you remove `urlencode()` with instantiating your `$ch`-var, you go just fine. `urlencode()` is definitely wrong here.

**Good:**

```
 $ch = curl_init($url);
```

**Bad:**

```
 $ch = curl_init(urlencode($url));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
```

instead of

```
$ch = curl_init(urlencode($url));
```